# Tomar sólo una captura en detección de objetos Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy trabajando en un código para que detecte portadas de libros, que se tome captura de la portada y pueda leer el título y mostrar en la consola el nombre, creé un archivo de entrenamiento en la gui cascade trainer para poder añadirlo a mi código, mi duda es la siguiente, cuando pongo frente a la cámara la portada del libro toma muchas capturas y se guardan todas ellas, entonces para el siguiente paso que es leer la captura para poder aplicarle filtros para detección de bordes y demás no logro leer la captura porque son muchas, quisiera que detectara la portada y se tomara sólo una captura, poner una portada diferente y de igual manera tomara sólo una captura, ¿alguna idea de cómo lograr esto?

Al capturar las imágenes de las portadas detectadas se guardan de la siguiente manera:

```
fecha_hora = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")

archivo = cv2.imwrite(carpeta + '/' + fecha_hora + str(y) + '.jpg', recuadro_portada)

list_of_files = glob.iglob('C:/rutadelacarpeta' + '/*')

latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)      

ruta = latest_file

rutacap = os.path.split(ruta)

ruta_archivo = rutacap[1]

img = cv2.imread(ruta_archivo)
```

Traté de conseguir el último archivo que se guardó de las capturas de la portada para leerlo y aplicar los demás filtros, sin embargo no lo lee, por eso busco una forma de que sólo se tome una captura y con una sola captura tal vez funcione

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Amigo es complicado validar que esta pasando por que sopongo que tienes una condicional que es donde estas realizando la toma de las fotos, solo nos estas dando a conocer la parte donde se almacena la foto, dejanos ver la condicion que es la que valida la cantidad de fotos que tiene que tomar el sistema

Comment: portadas = detectorportadas.detectMultiScale(gray,
              scaleFactor=1,
              minNeighbors=75,
              minSize=(7, 80))

 for (x, y, w, h) in portadas:
  cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
  recuadro_portada = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] Es la parte del código que va exactamente arriba del código de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Hola te comparto el script de mi proyecto de tesis para adquirir fotos. Basicamente el script recibe 4 parámetros:

1. Debes de indicar un alias para las imagenes. Puede ser "libro_" o "foto_libro" cualquier cosa.
2. Debes de indicar la cantidad de fotos que vas a tomar, en tu caso puede ser el numero de libros disponibles a capturar la portada, en mi caso fueron limones, tuve 3 clases por eso recibe el parámetro alias para indicar si iba a tomar fotos de "clase_verde_" o maduro, pinton.
3. Un indice, este este sirve para indicar desde que numero quieres comenzar, puedes iniciar con 1, o talvez cerraste el programa y vuelves a tomar fotos entonces ahora le pones un indice de 200, por ejemplo seria el numero en que se quedo antes. Este se une al alias "alias_indice" o "foto_1, fotos,2" el indice que le pongas se irá incrementando" y se le pondra como nombre al final del nombre de la foto.
4. La ruta donde guardar las imagenes puede ser en el mismo proyecto "fotos/" o "capturas/pruebas/" la ruta de la carpeta que desees.

   Entraras en un bucle que terminara cuando llegue a la cantidad de fotos que indicaste.

- El script te dice que presiones "c" para capturar una foto y "s" para "salir"

  Pruébalo espero te ayude, adáptalo a tu necesidad así ya no tendrás una cantidad de fotos tomadas en vano. !!

  Código: https://pastebin.com/aYfwD4zq

  PD: e intentado poner el codigo aqui pero sale todo desordenado y sin formato.